# wordpress => displaying contents in visual editor as stored in database without adding / removing br or p

Tags: wordpress, tags, editor

there already are many threads on this everywhere in www... none of them helped me yet.

hope someone can help me with my specific problem:

WordPress adds `/` strips `<p>`, `<br />`-tags but I just want to have the content in visual editor as it is stored in database without adding `/` removing `<p>`, `<br />` etc. (HTML-editor works fine, but I can't ask customers to use just HTML-editor).

my question: does anyone know why this is happening?

I tried it with plugins as TinyMCE-advanced and many others and also with adding code to functions.php, but nothing worked. I'm sure there must be a solution to this as it's a major reason to not use wp at all as wp seems not to be able to leave posts and pages just as they are stored in DB; it's just frustrating.

looking forward that someone found a solution to this.

any help is highly appreciated. thanks and best regards,

daniel

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your functions.php:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

That will disable the automatic addition/removal of break and p tags.

Comment: hi maiorano,
thanks for this hint, but unfortunately it doesn't work (tried it over and over again). 
now i also started to find out if qtranslate (v 2.5.29) disturbs something.

Comment: Maybe. Plugins are fairly notorious for causing unexpected behavior. My advice is to try leaving the remove_filter code in your functions.php file, then disable plugins one after the other, refreshing the page in question after each disable. If the page looks right after disabling a particular plugin, then you know it's a plugin problem.

Comment: wait, seems to work now, thanks maiorano!

there was some code in qtranslate_wp_hacks.php that seem to be the cause for the problem.
There was another patch, see here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42877/qtranslate-2-5-28-and-wordpress-3-3-1-issues/45371#45371

after undoing this (going back to original code) i didn't have the problem... tried and tested it during the last 30min, i'll have a deeper look on it.

best regards,
daniel

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark as answered if this covers everything you need.